# lim of $\lim_{ x\to \infty} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{e^x}$

Tags: limits

I have trouble solving the limit $\lim_{ x\to \infty} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}}{e^x}$, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20of%20%281%2B1%2Fx%29%5Ex%5E2%2Fe%5Ex%20as%20x-%3E%20infinity) says the answer is $e^{-1/2}$ instead of what I think (1).

Comment: Take the logarithm of the expression and use the power series expansion of $\ln(1+\frac1x)$.

Comment: no work shown, no effort displayed, nothing more than "wolfram alpha says", where is some effort to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[At first take the limiting value as a specified variable and then take logarithms for simplification. You may find the image attached of the handwritten solution. Hope this helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XghRE.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I will keep that in mind next time I post answers.